# Right derivative of continuous function nonnegative implies increasing function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $(a,b)$ such that $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\geq 0$$ exists for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Prove that $f$ is an increasing function on $(a,b)$, i.e. $f(x_1)\geq f(x_0)$ for all $x_1\geq x_0$, $x_0,x_1\in (a,b)$.

---

What I tried is proof by contradiction: Suppose there exists $x_1> x_0$ but $f(x_1)<f(x_0)$.

By Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists $x_0<c_1<x_1$ such that $f(x_1)<f(c_1)<f(x_0)$.

By IVT again, there exists $x_0<c_2<c_1$ such that $f(c_1)<f(c_2)<f(x_0)$.

By repeated use of IVT, there exists $$x_0<\dots c_3<c_2<c_1$$ with $$f(c_1)<f(c_2)<f(c_3)<\dots<f(x_0)$$

Since $c_n$ is decreasing and bounded below, $L:=\lim c_n$ exists. Similarly, $\lim f(c_n)=f(L)$ exists.

Then $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(L+h)-f(L)}{h}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(c_n)-f(L)}{c_n-L}\leq 0$$
since $f(c_n)-f(L)<0$ and $c_n-L>0$.

This is almost enough to be a contradiction had it been a strict $<0$. However at this point it seems not enough.

Thanks for any help. Note: I wouldn't rule out the possibility that the question itself is wrong..

Update: I think I got it. First prove the statement for a function $g$ with $\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\geq\epsilon>0$ on $(a,b)$. The above proof will do the job since now a contradiction can be achieved.

Then apply it to the function $g(x)=f(x)+\epsilon x$. Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, it can be proved that $f$ is increasing.

Comment: This is not a simple problem. Any answer must make use of some form of completeness of real numbers.  One approach is to use Dedekind's theorem. Also continuity  of the function is necessary.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Do you happen to know a reference for this question?

Comment: It's available in Hardy's Pure Mathematics. I will give page no question no in a minute or so.

Comment: It's page 208 question 19, 10th edition Hardy's A Course of Pure Mathematics.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I bumped into this post from another, which is similar. I gave there a counterexample for the case in which the function is not continuous. Here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3088518/if-the-right-derivative-is-positive-at-each-point-can-i-conclude-that-f-is-in/3097517#3097517.  I wonder however if continuity *is sufficient* to conclude that the statement holds true. If I'm not wrong, Hardy's hypothesis is different, being based directly on right "non-decreasingness" of the function, rather than on its right derivative.

Comment: @Matteo: I think you are correct. The fact that right derivative of $f$ at $c$ is non-negative does not necessarily imply that $f$ is non-decreasing from right at $c$. Classic example is $x^2\sin(1/x) $ at $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh exactly. Of course in that case the derivative isn't monotonic in any right neighborhood of 0. What happens if the right derivative *is* (non strictly) monotonic, I wonder? Do you know of any results on that?

Comment: @Matteo: I am not aware of any results dealing with functions whose right derivatives are monotone. Perhaps you could ask this as a question and let's see what our community has to say on that.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, I think I proved the statement, for continuous functions. If you want to have a look in the answer, I will appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See snapshot of Hardy's book question 19: [image]

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [Paramanand](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72031/paramanand-singh) in the comments, without continuity no conclusion on monotonicity at right neighborhoods of points in the domain can be drawn, even though $$f'_+(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \geq 0$$ 
$\forall x\in\Bbb R$. I show in this answer, too, for completeness, a counterexample that I already posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3088518/if-the-right-derivative-is-positive-at-each-point-can-i-conclude-that-f-is-in/3097517#3097517). It's a function $f(x)$ with  a well defined, non negative right derivative in $\Bbb R$, which however has $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) <0$ for $x>0$.

[image]

The red lines are parabolic envelopes with equations $y=-x|x|$ and $y=-\frac{1}{2}x|x|$ and the function is
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{\sqrt{2^{-k}}-\sqrt{2^{-k+1}}}{\sqrt[4]{2^{-k+1}}-\sqrt[4]{2^{-k}}}(x+\sqrt[4]{2^{-k+1}})- \sqrt{2^{-k+1}} & \left(-\sqrt[4]{2^{-k+1}}\leq x<-\sqrt[4]{2^{-k}}; \ k\in \Bbb Z\right)\\ 0 & (x=0)\\ \frac{\sqrt{2^{-k}}-\sqrt{2^{-k+1}}}{\sqrt[4]{2^{-k+1}}-\sqrt[4]{2^{-k}}}(x-\sqrt[4]{2^{-k+1}})+ \sqrt{2^{-k+1}}& \left(\sqrt[4]{2^{-k}}\leq x<\sqrt[4]{2^{-k+1}}; \ k\in \Bbb Z\right) .\end{cases}$$

---

Let us now demonstrate the following

> **Theorem** Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function in $[a,b]$ such that
>   \begin{equation}f'_+(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \geq 0, \ \ \forall x\in[a,b).\tag{1}\label{eq:1}\end{equation}
>   Then, for all $a\leq x \leq y\leq b$, $f(y)\geq f(x)$.

We will need the following variation of Rolle's Theorem.

> **Lemma** If $f(x)$ a is continuous function in $[a,b]$ with well defined right derivative $f'_+(x)$, and such that $f(a) = f(b)$, then there are points $\alpha,\beta\in[a,b]$ for which $f'_+(\alpha)\geq 0$ and $f'_+(\beta)\leq 0$.

Since $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, by Weierstrass Theorem it must reach its minimum and maximum in such interval. If $f(a) = f(b)$ is minimum and  maximum then the function is constant and the Lemma is proved. If $f(a) = f(b)$ is a minimum, then the maximum must be $\beta \in (a,b)$, and we have $f(x) \leq f(\beta)$. Hence, if $x\in(\beta, b] $, then we obtain $\frac{f(x)-f(\beta)}{x-\beta}\leq 0$. Therefore $f'_+(\beta) \leq 0$. Also, by minimality of $a$, we have $f(x) \geq f(a)$ for $x\in [a,b]$ so that $f'_+(a) \geq 0$. Similary, we can prove the statement if $f(a) = f(b)$ is a maximum, and if both minimum and maximum are in the *open* interval $(a,b)$.$\square$

Now we are ready to prove the Theorem, by contradiction. Suppose there are $c_1, c_2\in[a,b]$ such that $c_1 < c_2$ and $f(c_1) > f(c_2)$.

As when proving the Mean Value Theorem, consider an auxiliary function
$$F(x) = f(c_2)-f(x) + K(x-c_2),$$ with
$$K = \frac{f(c_2)-f(c_1)}{c_2-c_1}< 0.$$
It is easy to verify that $F(x)$ satisfies the Lemma hypotheses in $[c_1,c_2]$, with $F(c_1) = F(c_2) = 0$, and
\begin{equation}F'_+(x) = K-f'_+(x).\tag{2}\label{eq:2}\end{equation}
By the Lemma there is a point $c\in[c_1,c_2]$ such that
$$F'_+(c) \geq 0,$$ 
which, by \eqref{eq:2}, yields
$$f'_+(c) \leq K < 0,$$
a contradiction. $\blacksquare$

Comment: The proof of your lemma requires slight modification. Suppose the maximum is attained at $\beta$ then we have $f(x) \leq f(\beta) $ and there is no need of strict inequality.

Comment: Nice proof altogether +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thanks! I'll make the correction!